# Output XML from JSF2 with Facelets

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, facelets

I would like to return a well-formed XML document when a user clicks on a specific link in my JSF2 application.

I have the link working which goes to an xhtml page - however I cannot get the page to return XML to the browser. Eventually the XML will be generated by a backing bean (pulling the data from the DB). But first I am trying to get a simple demo working with hardcoded data in the page.

At the moment the page always returns wrapped in

```
<html> ... </html>.
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using REST web services? Check out the quick tutorial at: http://seamframework.org/Documentation/CDIQuickstartForMavenUsers to see how to get simple example with REST functionality.